# mysql Rand() not working

Tags: mysql

In my case i need to display particular item at the first, other than that i need to select randomly . so i used the following query

```
"SELECT * FROM table_test1 WHERE id = 3  UNION( SELECT * FROM table_test1 WHERE id <> 3   ORDER BY RAND() ) "
```

But it doesn't selects randomly

my table

```
id  name
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
```

this selects always C-A-B-D-E

can any one explain theory of union ?

Whats wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_test1
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN id = 3 THEN -1
            ELSE RAND()
          END
```

As Quassnoi points out in the comments the `ORDER BY` in the second statement is completely ignored.

Semantically if you want the whole results to be sorted by a particular order you need an `order by` that applies to the whole query anyway or your solution might end up relying on assumptions about implementation that break in future versions.

Comment: @gowri - Shame, I was sure that would be it! How about my second suggestion?

Comment: second suggestion works !but **SELECT * FROM table_test1 WHERE id = 3  UNION All( SELECT * FROM table_test1 WHERE id <> 3   ORDER BY RAND() )** it doesn't why. and i also like to know about **THEN -1** which means !

Comment: @gowri - I'm not sure. As I said I didn't think the `order by` would be guaranteed in that case but I did actually expect `UNION ALL` to work. Maybe `MySQL` just optimises it out as there is no `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: @gowri: `MySQL` ignores innermost `ORDER BY` in the second query. You can see in the plan that the `filesort` isn't even executed.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Would that still be the case if there was a `LIMIT`clause? Does MySQL even allow `LIMIT` there? (I haven't got it installed on this machine to test)

Comment: @Martin: with `LIMIT` it would sort of course and the results would be different every time. However, I believe the @op wanted to get the whole list but in arbitrary order after the second row.

Comment: sorry to ask many questions can you please explain **THEN -1** in your query

Comment: @gowri - `rand()` returns a number between 0 and 1. -1 is guaranteed to be before any such value when sorted ascending.

Comment: @Quassnoi - So I guess you *could* put a very high value for `LIMIT` and it *might* work but it would be similar to using `TOP 100 PERCENT .. ORDER BY` in SQL Server Views. In SQL Server 2000 that used to work but people relying on it had a bit of a nasty shock when 2005 came out!

Answer (score 0):

UNION deletes duplicates. To do that, it sorts the result set, hence the order you get. You can get around that using UNION ALL, which does not delete duplicates, and hence does not need to sort.

Also, http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/ Do not use ORDER BY RAND(). It does not scale.